# APFS Container Resize error code is 49153 in High Sierra

Tags: disk-utility, partition, high-sierra

I am trying to resize my partition using the following

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 450g ExFAT Ubuntu 50g
```

However I am getting the error:

```
APFS Container Resize error code is 49153
Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container 
structures
```

I followed the instructions listed on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424915/apfs-container-resize-error-code-is-49153 but they are not working for me. I also turned off automatic backups and rebooted my machine and still nothing. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I sorted the error

1. Reboot the machine
2. Go into the 'Time Machine' pane of the System Preferences
3. Right/Ctrl click the Time Machine drive icon
4. Click 'Don't use {drive name} for Time Machine'
5. Run `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999999` for the last time in Terminal
6. Resize the disk.

Answer (score 0):

While this might not answer your exact question, I have struggled with a similar error (both in Mojave Disk Utility and on the terminal using diskutil), getting error "49157" trying to shrink a container from 1TB to 100GB.

In the end, the thing that worked for me was to shrink it in a couple of smaller increments: first shrinking to 900GB, then 800GB, then it seemed that a shrink to 100GB worked directly (it might have worked after the first shrink to 900GB for all I know, but I was frustrated and didn't want to push my luck at that stage).

I've encountered similar situations with partition resizing software on Windows, where some data on the disk was in the way of making a large change to partition sizes, but the software could handle the operation in a couple of smaller steps.

For those hitting the same problem while shrinking APFS containers, this might help. My guess is that the "two or three step shrink" would have probably worked fine in Disk Utility too (for those who don't enjoy pounding away at the terminal).